# Problems plotting log-likelihood-function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to plot a log-likelihood-function using ggplot2;
the function is defined by

```
y <- rpois(100, lambda = 3)

f_1 <- function(z) -100*z + sum(log(1/factorial(y)*z^y)).
```

When trying to calculate values of f_1, everything works fine (e.g. f_1(1) = -316.1308)

But when I try to plot f_1 using ggplot2, an error pops up:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(z = 0), mapping = aes(z=z))

p <- p + stat_function(fun = f_1)
```

> error: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object
> length".

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function must be written to handle length > 1 vectors, because `stat_function` will pass a vector of values to your function, rather than applying the function to each x-axis value on the plot individually. If you try e.g. `f_1(0:10)` you get the same warning, confirming this function does not handle length > 1 vectors properly. The problem is with `z^y`. If `z` and `y` are both vectors the behavior is to apply `^` to each element of `z` and `y` having the same index. See for example `(1:10)^(1:10)`. Now what happens when you try `(1:10)^(1:20)`? The warning is telling you the lengths don't match, so the behavior may be unexpected.

You can vectorize your function by just using `Vectorize`, and this should give the plot you expect

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(z = 0), mapping = aes(z=z))

p <- p + stat_function(fun = Vectorize(f_1))
```